# Adding Picture from Excel to PictureBox but empty picture show up

Tags: vb.net, excel, picturebox

i have a code that add a group of several pictures. Then my program ran well on Win7 with Office 2010 that picturebox can show picture.
But, when my program ran in WinXP with office 2003. It can't show any picture. Does anyone know why?

This is my code

```
For Each sp As EXCEL.Shape In xlsheet.Shapes
                    sp.Copy()
                    picname = sp.Name

                    If Strings.Left(picname, 5) = "Group" Then
                        If Clipboard.ContainsImage Then
                            MsgBox("have image")
                            xlPic = Clipboard.GetImage
                            PictureBox1.Image = xlPic
                            ImageList1.Images.Add(xlPic)
                        End If
                    End If
                    For Each Me.xlsheet In xlbook.Sheets
                        If xlsheet.Name.Equals("Reference") Then
                            xlsheet = xlapp.Sheets("Reference")
                            timerlamp.Enabled = True
                            For Each sp1 As EXCEL.Shape In xlsheet.Shapes
                                If Strings.Left(picname, 5) = "Group" Then
                                    sp1.Copy()
                                    If Clipboard.ContainsImage Then
                                        xlPic = Clipboard.GetImage
                                        ImageList1.Images.Add(xlPic)
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
```

Comment: I'm having some difficulties understanding your code. Why do you have so much duplicate code? Why is the loop that iterates over all sheets inside the loop that iterates over all shapes in a sheet?

Comment: Sorry, i'm still beginner of programmer. If can, can you tell me what need i do to change my code to be not duplicate?