# ClipBoard won't work in runtime

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

I have ask a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266901/adding-picture-from-excel-to-picturebox-but-empty-picture-show-up) before, but there are seem no one can answer it.
So, i change my question now. I have found out actually this code work and copy the picture to the clipboard. But when the code run at WinXp, it seem to not work even can't detect Clipboard.ContainImage. So does anyone know how to fix this or any guide?

```
For Each sp As EXCEL.Shape In xlsheet.Shapes
                    sp.Copy()
                    picname = sp.Name
                    If Strings.Left(picname, 5) = "Group" Then
                        If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage Then
                            xlPic = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage
                            PictureBox1.Image = xlPic
                            ImageList1.Images.Add(xlPic)
                        Else
                            sp.Copy()
                            xlPic = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage
                            PictureBox1.Image = xlPic
                            ImageList1.Images.Add(xlPic)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
```

**UPDATE**

Actually i got no ERROR in these code. But the problem is. When i run this application on Win XP. The Clipboard.ContainsImage can't detect and my PictureBox can't get the image that contain in Clipboard. I tried to paste to Paint, it can, but running by program, it can't. When run in Win 7, it was run well.

Comment: what error do you get when you try to run this?

Answer (score 1):

try this, it worked for me with Win XP, VS2010 and Excel2007 :

```
 appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 wbExcel = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename)
 wsExcel = wbExcel.Worksheets(1)

 For Each oShape As Shape In wsExcel.Shapes

                    If oShape.Name.StartsWith("Picture") Then
                        Clipboard.Clear()
                        oShape.CopyPicture(XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap)

                        If Clipboard.ContainsImage() Then
                            Dim img As Image
                            img = Clipboard.GetImage()
                            PictureBox1.Image = img
                            PictureBox1.Visible = True
                            Exit For
                    End If
                Next oShape
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (reliably) expect to copy data to the clipboard and then immediately be able to paste it.  Other applications are reacting to the clipboard update, and quite a lot can happen in the meantime.  It's possible/likely that you cannot paste the image because some other application has opened the clipboard for pasting.  You may be able to introduce a sleep() after the copy, and get away with that.
Keep in mind that it is POOR PRACTICE to use the clipboard this way. The clipboard is provided for the convenience of the USER, not the PROGRAMMER.

Comment: For what you said, i was understand. Actually i have test the clipboard as it's as i want or not. It's actually contain what i what. The matter is why it can't work on Win XP. i have test by closing all software except my program]

Answer (score -1):

try replacing all instances of

```
sp.copy()
```

with

```
my.computer.clipboard.setimage(sp)
```

The setImage method documentation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setimage.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About that i have tried. I get COM error back then. I have search on the internet for some days. And the link you add, i have look for it before i ask this question.